# Selenium + Nose - N-1 Tests runs headless

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Having some strangeness go on.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = None
class TestThreshold:

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    def waitForId(self,type,id):
        try:
            element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((type,id))
            WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(element_present)
        except TimeoutException:
            print "Timed out waiting for page to load"
    def setUp(self):
        # code that uses driver.login to login

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close();

    def test_login(self):
        # a test with assertion

    def test_feature(self):
        # a test with assertion


    def test_admin(self):
        # another test with assertion
```

When I run `nosetests` Chrome browser pops up. It stays on a blank page for a bit, then finally runs the `test_login` and `test_feature` then quits.

All 3 tests pass (got `Ran 3 tests` in CLI with an `OK`), but only 1 is visually shown. Two of the three ran in a headless type mode while the page was blank for a bit.

How can I have it run all tests from start to finish without headless? (And if I wanted to, how can i run them both headless?)

I also notice that if I keep adding tests, it always will run N-1 tests headless (one will be ran visually)

Answer (score 0):

So this made me laugh. The reason is because there are multiple Chrome windows stacked on top of each other. It is running in parallel not sequentially.